# What do I need to provide, for someone to point their domain to my host?

Tags: dns, subdomain, point

I have a host and my own domain, lets say: www.mysite.com, on this host I have created a site: sub.mysite.com

Another person owns www.domain.com and I need him to point the domain to sub.mysite.com, however I am going away tomorrow and would like to just leave him the details he needs in order to point www.domain.com to sub.mysite.com, what would those details be?

Thanks,
-Anton

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Name Server addresses, which can be found searching here:

http://who.is

**edit:**

Bear in mind that in addition to changing the name servers for the domain, you will also need change your [host's] server configuration to manage the traffic redirection.

Name Server addresses point to a server, not a domain. You want the name servers to match for your current domain and the domain you want moving. This means they will both find the same 'computer'. It is down to the 'computer' (server) to then provide the right files; in this situation, it is achieved by configuring the server to forward traffic arriving from 'newdomain.com' to 'sub.olddomain.com'.

If using the CPanel web management control panel, this is done in the 'Addon Domains' section:

Enter the domain to be pointed in the 'new domain name' field, then set the 'Document Root' field to point to the folder hosting the contents of your subdomain. (e.g. /public_html/sub)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that's what I thought really, but I just needed confirmation! :)

Comment: Pleased to help! Of course, don't forget that you will also need to add this as an additional domain and point it to the subdomain through your (or your host's) control panel (or web server configuration files etc.). I'm sure you already know this, but thought I'd say for anyone else reading who doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, actaully, I am not 100% sure on this part myself. I am guessing that if he simply uses the name server addresses, the link www.domain.com would point to www.mysite.com/domain.com, and from here I would redirect www.mysite.com/domain.com to sub.mysite.com? What would a good redirect method be here?

Comment: The Name Server addresses point to a server, not your domain. You want the name servers to match for your domain and the domain you want adding - this means they will both find the same 'computer'. It is down to the 'computer' to then provide the right files; in this situation, it is achieved by configuring the server to forward traffic arriving from 'newdomain.com' to 'sub.olddomain.com'. edit: are you using a webhost, if so - it should have some sort of control panel, like CPanel or Plesk (if that still exists?) .. it is straightforward to configure such redirects through those systems

Comment: I do have CPanel, and I was looking at CNAME or A records, however CNAME only allows me to point (somedomain).webbr.org. to any domain and A records require an IP address.

Comment: Nevermind, your explanation helped me find it :) Thanks again.

Comment: In CPanel, go to: 'Addon Domains'. Enter the domain to be pointed in the 'new domain name' field, then set the 'Document Root' field to point to the folder hosting the contents of your subdomain. (e.g. /public_html/sub)

Comment: Brilliant :) Care to share your solution?

Comment: You just did, it was under Addon Domains :) Perhaps you could also edit the answer and add that while I would have to provide the name server addresses, I would also have to add an addom domain redirection.

Comment: Haha ty for the validation ;) And have updated my answer as suggested.